# How convert [this] XML => XSD => C# class => load class? (Usual way yields errors)

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xsd

Setup:
VS2017 C#
House Bill XML ([here](https://www.govtrack.us/data/congress/115/bills/hr/hr10/))
[*The above link is to a folder on govtrack, which will all be going away at the end of this summer.*]

thesis: MS' xsd.exe creates an .xsd and .cs that against the same data (XML) used to create them, *fails*.

Sample: Congress: 115 (current) House (hr) Bill hr10 (random)
The target to convert is the file: **data.xml**, and it is typical.

...a few lines from data.xml:

```
<bill session="115" type="h" number="10" updated="2017-04-27T14:15:09Z">
  <state datetime="2017-04-26">REFERRED</state>
  <status>
    <introduced datetime="2017-04-26"/>
  </status>
  <introduced datetime="2017-04-26"/>
  <titles>
    <title type="short" as="introduced">Financial CHOICE Act of 2017</title>
    <title type="official" as="introduced">To create hope and opportunity for investors, consumers, and entrepreneurs by ending bailouts and Too Big to Fail, holding Washington and Wall Street accountable, eliminating red tape to increase access to capital and credit, and repealing the provisions of the Dodd-Frank Act that make America less prosperous, less stable, and less free, and for other purposes.</title>
    <title type="display">Financial CHOICE Act of 2017</title>
  </titles>
  <sponsor id="400175"/>
    [...]
  <committees>
    <committee code="HSED" name="House Education and the Workforce" activity="Referral"/>
    <committee code="HSBU" name="House Budget" activity="Referral"/>
    <committee code="HSRU" name="House Rules" activity="Referral"/>
    <committee code="HSPW" name="House Transportation and Infrastructure" activity="Referral"/>
    <committee code="HSGO" name="House Oversight and Government Reform" activity="Referral"/>
    <committee code="HSJU" name="House Judiciary" activity="Referral"/>
    <committee code="HSWM" name="House Ways and Means" activity="Referral"/>
    <committee code="HSAG" name="House Agriculture" activity="Referral"/>
    <committee code="HSBA" name="House Financial Services" activity="Referral"/>
  </committees>
  <relatedbills/>
  <subjects/>
  <amendments/>
  <committee-reports/>
</bill>
```

I run it against xsd:

```
F:\politic\stats\hr10>xsd data.xml
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.6.1055.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    Writing file 'F:\politic\stats\hr10\data.xsd'.

F:\politic\stats\hr10>dir
 Volume in drive F is VBOX_shared
 Volume Serial Number is 0000-0801

 Directory of F:\politic\stats\hr10

04/27/2017  01:33 PM                24 fdsys_billstatus-lastmod.txt
04/30/2017  09:34 PM             4,920 data.xsd
04/27/2017  01:33 PM             7,918 data.json
04/27/2017  01:33 PM             3,584 data.xml
04/27/2017  01:33 PM                24 data-fromfdsys-lastmod.txt
04/27/2017  10:03 AM    <DIR>          text-versions
04/27/2017  01:33 PM            17,415 fdsys_billstatus.xml
               6 File(s)         37,981 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  87,839,031,296 bytes free
```

The next step is to convert the **data.xsd** to a C# class:

```
F:\politic\stats\hr10>xsd data.xsd /classes /l:CS
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.6.1055.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'F:\politic\stats\hr10\data.cs'.

F:\politic\stats\hr10>dir
 Volume in drive F is VBOX_shared
 Volume Serial Number is 0000-0801

 Directory of F:\politic\stats\hr10

04/27/2017  01:33 PM                24 fdsys_billstatus-lastmod.txt
04/30/2017  09:34 PM             4,920 data.xsd
04/27/2017  01:33 PM             7,918 data.json
04/27/2017  01:33 PM             3,584 data.xml
04/27/2017  01:33 PM                24 data-fromfdsys-lastmod.txt
04/30/2017  09:38 PM            14,666 data.cs
04/27/2017  10:03 AM    <DIR>          text-versions
04/27/2017  01:33 PM            17,415 fdsys_billstatus.xml
               7 File(s)         52,647 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  87,839,014,912 bytes free
```

Great! No errors!

I now pluck an example off the Interwebs (Console project, full generic code, with original comments, below):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program x = new Program();
            x.DesrXml();
        }

        public void DesrXml()
        {
            try
            {
                bill myObject = new bill();
                // Construct an instance of the XmlSerializer with the type  
                // of object that is being deserialized.  
                XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(bill));
                // To read the file, create a FileStream.  
                FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.Open);
                // Call the Deserialize method and cast to the object type.  
                myObject = (bill)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
            } catch (Exception ex ) {
                Console.WriteLine("ToString() " + ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Message: " + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("end...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The errors created are (apologies in advance for wrapping, as text is copied from output console *as-is*):

```
ToString() System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'introduced[]' to 'introduced'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'billTitlesTitle[]' to 'billTitlesTitle'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'billCosponsorsCosponsor[]' to 'billCosponsorsCosponsor'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'billActionsAction[]' to 'billActionsAction'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'billCommitteesCommittee[]' to 'billCommitteesCommittee'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'introduced' to 'introduced[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'billTitlesTitle' to 'billTitlesTitle[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'billCosponsorsCosponsor' to 'billCosponsorsCosponsor[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'billActionsAction' to 'billActionsAction[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'billCommitteesCommittee' to 'billCommitteesCommittee[]'

   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.DesrXml() in c:\users\pat\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 30
Message: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'introduced[]' to 'introduced'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'billTitlesTitle[]' to 'billTitlesTitle'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'billCosponsorsCosponsor[]' to 'billCosponsorsCosponsor'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'billActionsAction[]' to 'billActionsAction'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'billCommitteesCommittee[]' to 'billCommitteesCommittee'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'introduced' to 'introduced[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'billTitlesTitle' to 'billTitlesTitle[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'billCosponsorsCosponsor' to 'billCosponsorsCosponsor[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'billActionsAction' to 'billActionsAction[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'billCommitteesCommittee' to 'billCommitteesCommittee[]'

StackTrace:    at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.DesrXml() in c:\users\pat\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 30
end...
```

So I looked at just the first error, on introduced[]:

```
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'introduced[]' to 'introduced'
```

...in the **data.cs** class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class introduced {

    private string datetimeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string datetime {
        get {
            return this.datetimeField;
        }
        set {
            this.datetimeField = value;
        }
    }
}
[...]
 private introduced[][] statusField;

 private introduced[] introducedField;
[...]
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("introduced", typeof(introduced), IsNullable=false)]
    public introduced[][] status {
        get {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("introduced")]
    public introduced[] introduced {
        get {
            return this.introducedField;
        }
        set {
            this.introducedField = value;
        }
    }
[...]
```

It doesn't take a rocket surgeon to figure out what I'm trying to do: Ultimately, if MS can write code it can use, I'll be using EF to store all the historical data in a DB. Once ingested, I don't need to go through this exercise again. I'll share how I did it on my blogs.

Note: There are other sources of bill and other US Govt data. Many may be better suited for this. If you go to the govtrack site, you will see that there are dozens of other classes that need to be created to permit full conversion from XML to RDBMS/NoSQL...

Comment: What are you trying to do with the XML? Interacting with XML can be done more straightforward with the [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387063.aspx) or [`XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) API.

Comment: Grab what you need using XmlDocument and SelectNodes(strXPath) and be done with it.  Those POCOs are worthless for getting XML into a DB, even when / if you do get them working.

Comment: @Romoku thanks for the note. I tried to say that After I used the XML to create a class, I tried above to load that class with the same XML. After that, I can use EF to get it into the DB... I'm hoping the error in xsd.exe is such that I can go through the class and clean it up, as this one class will work for a long time. It is complex, so I was hoping to do it with xsd.exe

Comment: @WilliamWalseth thanks for your note. They never tell you: "<i>Those POCOs are worthless for getting XML into a DB, even when / if you do get them working.</i>" when you use it! The errors don't mean anything to anyone, though? I'll try XmlDocument in the mean time...

Comment: I'm open to better tools, as the classes are very complex. With govtrack going offline, I've focused on GPO. What do you guys/gals use if not xsd.exe?